# Create new progressive web app (PWA) using angular 5

Tags: angular, mobile, command-line-interface, progressive-web-apps

I have read many article on angular 5 blogs about new features of angular5. It mainly focuses on development of Progressive web application. I have tried to create new progressive web application for mobile. But it is not working. Files/components needed for mobile application is not created while new project is created using angular cli.

Can any one help me how to create new PWA for mobile using angular 5?

I am using angular cli 1.5

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Angular cli 1.6. [Release notes](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.6.0)